# Azure Log Analytics query if property exists

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to check if my `customDimensions` object has a property and then only count the queries that have the property set to something. It is counting queries that don't have the `SupportedLanguage` property in the `customDimensions` object.

Here is my current query:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| summarize COUNT=count(customDimensions.SupportedLanguage) by lang=tostring(customDimensions.SupportedLanguage)
| render piechart
```

I tried doing the following but it didn't work:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| where customDimensions.SupportedLanguage
| summarize COUNT=count(customDimensions.SupportedLanguage) by lang=tostring(customDimensions.SupportedLanguage)
| render piechart
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can leverage [isnotempty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/isnotemptyfunction) function for this purpose:

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(7d)
| where isnotempty(customDimensions.SupportedLanguage)
```